# How to figure out password from keystore file?

Tags: password, keystore

I'm using [this](https://capgemini.github.io/blockchain/ethereum-docker-compose/) to create a private Ethereum network for some tests. It comes pre-loaded with 10 accounts, each with 20 ether. However, I can't seem to find the password for these accounts. An example keystore file is

```
{  
   "address":"007ccffb7916f37f7aeef05e8096ecfbe55afc2f",
   "Crypto":{  
      "cipher":"aes-128-ctr",
      "ciphertext":"44600de3be08153de243f0de344b9841c774a2fcd5b7f3406b9ea9a42c8be97b",
      "cipherparams":{  
         "iv":"9ca680df904bc0138d2d52f9c432a797"
      },
      "kdf":"scrypt",
      "kdfparams":{  
         "dklen":32,
         "n":262144,
         "p":1,
         "r":8,
         "salt":"a6524c4ef60060476f2e47dea7f5945aac8159019d3bf5275a683c1970d03c40"
      },
      "mac":"4daf73bc6da7f75beb9a8ea28896c5f1f074fb8cd54880fa9a4e34700dc0ee00"
   },
   "id":"2615dd6a-6d73-4b05-a02d-257b0fd28d3a",
   "version":3
}
```

but this seems to contain just encrypted data with salt (like mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/745/if-someone-gets-my-geth-keystore-files-can-they-spend-my-eth-without-knowing-my)). If not here, and being that it is not specified in the docs, where should I look for the password? Meaning, this is designed to be a plug and play private network with Docker so the passwords should be easily accessible, I just don't know where to look.

Comment: They have an empty password see https://github.com/Capgemini-AIE/ethereum-docker/issues/19, but you can replace those files with your own if you want passwords.